# Proof involving infinite series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am practicing for a final exam for Mathematics 2 course in university. I study EE. In my practice problems there is an exercise that asks to prove the following statement:

*If $\ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ is a convergent series and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n$ is a divergent series, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(a_n+b_n)$ is also a divergent series.*

I've was firstly unsure of how to approach this proof but this is how I eventually went about doing so. I was hoping that someone could verify the validity of the proof and if it was actually rigorous enough to be consider valid. So this was my thought proccess:

At first I wanted to try to prove it in terms of the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. I know that there is a theorem that states the following:

> If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(x_n)$ is a convergent series, then the $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(x_n) = 0$.

Since $\ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ is a convergent series, there exists the value A which represents the sum of the series. And also $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(a_n) = 0$. Then I wanted to conclude that since $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(b_n)$ is divergent series, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(n_n)\ne0$, which I quicky figured out was not correct. The above mention theorem would only provide the inverse fact that if the $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(b_n) \ne 0$ the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n$ would be divergent, which was of no use to me. Obvious counterexample to my logic was the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{n})$ which diverges even though the $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(\frac{1}{n})=0$. Because of this I went the other route, and finally ended up with the proof the validity of which I am questioning.

First I considered the limit definition of an infinite series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(x_n) = \lim_{m \to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m(x_n).$$
Using this I find the following:$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(a_n+b_n) = \lim_{m \to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m(a_n+b_n).$$
Now since there is now a "finite" number of elements under the limit, I believe that I can now separate the sum into two sums. This is similar to how the proof of linearity of convergent series was done in my textbook, but I am questioning this step since the second series is divergent. Though in a lack of better idea I continued like this: $$\lim_{m \to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m(a_n+b_n) = \lim_{m \to +\infty}( A_m + B_m )$$
where $A_m$ and $B_m$ are the sequences defined by: $$A_m = \sum_{n=1}^m a_n \quad and \quad B_m = \sum_{n=1}^m b_n.$$

Since I've know written the original series as in terms of sequences I remembered that there was a theorem which roughly states that:

> For two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} x_n = c, c \in {\Bbb R}$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} y_n = DNE$, the limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(x_n+y_n) = DNE$.

Now, at least in my simple mind, the rest was easy. We know that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}A_m = A$ and that the $\lim_{n \to +\infty}Bn$ diverges, so then the original series, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(a_n+b_n)$ diverges as well, Q.E.D.

I realize that his was really long post and the proof but I really wanted to write everything out in detail. I am hoping that someone is going to find time and read through all of it and provide me with corrections, wherever they are needed. Thanks a lot for your effort and excuse my English spelling and syntax, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me! And so does your English spelling and syntax :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! can you explain to me this one thing that I am not sure of. What is the EXACT reason that makes separation of the sums under the limit a valid step? The way I see it is that, inside a limit, when m is not going go inifinity,, both sums are finite and can therefore be separated. Since I am never writing the step where i have sum1 + sum2 there is no invalid equalities? If I was to write that the sum(an+bn) = lim(sum(an)) + lim(sum(bn)), would that be valid? What I am not really sure is when can I separate sums and when I can't. Can you explain this to me in the form of an answer?

Comment: It is fact that if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent sequences, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n +  \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n $. Apply this to the sequences of partial sums and you win.

Comment: @DanielApsley I am aware that I can do this sorts of manipulations when they do converge. I've not stated my question correctly. Can I ever separate a convergent and a divergent series? Or can I ever separate two divergent series? Can I pull out a constant in front of a divergent series. All of this is valid for every convergent series, but the divergent ones are what really really really confuses me

Comment: Ah I see, in general you cannot separate a convergent and divergent series like that. This would be good to use in a proof by contrapositive, where you assume that the sum $(a_n + b_n)$ converges. Then, $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n + b_n) - \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) - a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ converges by the quoted fact.

Comment: @DanielApsley I've found a proof similar to what you are mentioning later today, after posting this. It's a much more elegant proof then mine. Then in the same thread I've found one proof that is basically 99% the same as mine. I think it was done by someone much smarter than me and as far as I can see mine and that proof are equivalent, so I guess mine is right as well. The thing that was noted in the question was that when partial sums are used, with upper bound tending to infinity (i mean when you write an infinite series as a limit), then those two sums can be separated